# R: Pasting information from one or two rows above into an empty cell if the entry ends in a letter

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big dataframe where I have some empty cells that I wish to fill.
Snapshot of dataframe is here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HfZ2.png)

I want to somehow fill the empty cells if the accession ends in a letter with a paste of 'the next accession code above if it does not end in a letter + accession code of that row'
E.g For row 3: Q15149 V144M, For row 4, Q15149 V117M.

Any help on how to tackle this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  Accession = c("Q09666", "Q15149", "V144M", "V117M"),
  Gene.Symbol = c("AHNAK", "PLEC", NA, NA)
)
data
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Accession Gene.Symbol
#>   <chr>     <chr>      
#> 1 Q09666    AHNAK      
#> 2 Q15149    PLEC       
#> 3 V144M     <NA>       
#> 4 V117M     <NA>

fills <-
  data %>%
  transmute(id = row_number(), Accession = Accession) %>%
  filter(!Accession %>% str_ends("[A-Z]"))
fills
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id Accession
#>   <int> <chr>    
#> 1     1 Q09666   
#> 2     2 Q15149

data %>%
  mutate(
    Gene.Symbol = Gene.Symbol %>% map2_chr(row_number(), ~ {
      ifelse(!is.na(.x), .x, fills %>% filter(id <= .y) %>%
        pull(Accession) %>%
        last())
    })
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Accession Gene.Symbol
#>   <chr>     <chr>      
#> 1 Q09666    AHNAK      
#> 2 Q15149    PLEC       
#> 3 V144M     Q15149     
#> 4 V117M     Q15149
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Just what I needed and I just updated the gene.symbol column to incorporate the the accession code as well so Q15149 V144M and Q15149 V117M.